# CSS - form not well formatted on CPanel

Tags: html, css, forms, cpanel

Im adding a form to a website. When working on my computer it looks as I want but when I update it on the server it gets unformated.

This is what I want it to look like

[image]

and this is how it looks like when on-line

[image]

Code I've tried:

HTML

Subscreve a nossa mailing list
                
                    Nome
                    
                
                
                    E-mail

```
            <div class="clear mc-field-group"><input type="submit" value="Subscrever" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button "></div>

            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear ">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_b979d0f70b0c2b6cf424c7227_da6d6427a3" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>           
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text'; }(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

CSS:

```
#signup{
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #FEC800;
}

#signup h1{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}

#mc_embed_signup{
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.mc-field-group{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    /*background-color: red;*/
}

.mc_embed_signup form{
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#mce-EMAIL, #mce-FNAME{
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have also tried CSS (similar result)

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], select {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: please make jsfiddle or snippet of it

Comment: @mcrosa: Most probably your online html don't read the css file correctly, can you confirm that there are no errors in your console?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap and not have this meta on your page then this might happen. check second point in below URL.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp